# How to align a input form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not strong in frontend development :) I'm using bootstrap for created a form. But it isn't look fine. How could I align my input form in one column?

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label for="exampleInputPrice" class="personal-form-labels">Purchase Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPrice" placeholder="$$$">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label for="exampleInputLoan" class="personal-form-labels">Loan Amont</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLoan" placeholder="$$$">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center block-buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dxMx.png)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47937132/edit) your question rather than adding comments. Also, which Bootstrap version do you use?

Comment: You can add class to input and set float:right attribute for this

Comment: @chade_ I've done. 4 ver.

Comment: @sauero no, it isn't helps

Comment: I think you are used Bootstrap-4  bootstrap Horizontal form not support in bootstrap -4 ,if you want like that use  bootstrap 3 , read this https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use of `display:table-*`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.form-inline {
  display: table-row;
}

.form-inline label, .form-inline input {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 0 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label for="exampleInputPrice" class="personal-form-labels">Purchase Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPrice" placeholder="$$$">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label for="exampleInputLoan" class="personal-form-labels">Loan Amont</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLoan" placeholder="$$$">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center block-buttons">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah! It's nice to work. It's really good idea. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , **bootstrap Horizontal form** not support in **bootstrap -4** 
 [Not supported](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)  ,use **bootstrap 3**

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">





<form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Purchase Price">Purchase Price</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPrice" placeholder="$$$">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Loan Amont">Loan Amont</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLoan" placeholder="$$$">
      </div>
    </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">        
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

bootsrap-3 doc https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_horizontal&stacked=h

Comment: I've tried to do it but it isnt look good in my jumbotron. String aren't opposite in line

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4 Try This :

```
    <form>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="exampleInputPrice" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Purchase Price</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPrice" placeholder="$$$">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="exampleInputLoan" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Loan Amont</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLoan" placeholder="$$$">
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sv2j08dd/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Modulation:**
                

             **Glass thickness:**

css:
.inputs span{ display: inline-block; width: 60%; padding: 0 0 15px 0; }
.inputs span input{ width: 30%; float: left; height:25px;padding: 0 5px;}

.inputs{width: 100%;float: left;padding: 0 25px; box-sizing: border-box;}

.inputs label{width: 20%;float: left;}